# Does ostensibly imply something is not as it seems?

Tags: meaning

I am aware that the word *ostensibly* is a rough synonym of *apparently*. But I am trying to nail-down the precise meaning of the former word.

Indeed, Collins defines Ostensibly as meaning

> apparently; seemingly

But the Cambridge Dictionary has the following definition (my emphasis):

> in a way that appears or claims to be one thing **when it is really something else**:

So my question is, if one uses ostensibly in a sentence will people normally read it as "apparently" or will it normally be taken to imply "apparently, but not really"?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are right in thinking that *ostensibly* implies some suspicion. Oxford Languages has:

> As appears or is stated to be true, though not necessarily so; apparently.
> "the party secretary resigned, ostensibly from ill health"

The example sentence implies "He *says* it was from ill-health, but we suspect there were other reasons too".

Answer (score 3):

Merriam-Webster's note on etymology of *ostensible* also suggests a difference in implied and actual meaning:

> Ostensible comes from Latin *ostendere*, meaning "to show," and the word suggests a discrepancy between a declared or implied aim or reason and the true one.

Answer (score 1):

> Does ostensibly imply something is not as it seems?

If we look at the OED entry for the adjective from which the adverb is derived, we see that the short answer is “Yes”, but the long answer is “Yes, but not absolutely always.”

> **2. Declared, avowed, professed; presented *(esp. untruthfully or misleadingly)* as actual; stated or appearing to be genuine, *but not necessarily so*. Frequently *implicitly or explicitly opposed to actual or real.*** Now the principal sense.
>
> 1943   M. Samuel tr. S. Asch Apostle ii. i. 224   Despite his ostensible attitude of indifference toward the plebs which had hailed him, Agrippa was pleased by the popular reception.
>
> 1992   Spy (N.Y.) May 14/2   One wonders if this ostensible pat on the back wasn't actually a sly, bitchy dig.

Note that in the 1943 quote, there was no real “attitude of indifference”, but in the 1992 quote the writer seems to be conceding that the pat on the back could have been genuine.

And, to show the exception, we have:

> 1837   S. Smith Works (1867) II. 249   He put his trust really where he put his trust ostensibly.

Which we understand as “He puts his trust where he puts his apparent trust.”

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

Where it differs from "apparently" is that [the etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ostensibly) relates to "held out as true, real, actual, or intended". "Apparently" would be "as it appears to me", while "ostensibly" would be "as held out by someone else", so we're dealing with a difference between our own perception, and something that someone else is telling us.

Whether this makes it more or less worthy of suspicion will depend on who is "holding out" the idea. It's often used to suggest things might not be as they seem, but using "apparently" in its place would make that no less of a suggestion - if the speaker / writer believed what was being reported, they wouldn't use either word.

It's possible that someone might trust someone else's word over their own perception, but that's going to be very specific to the relationship between them.

It's used to express doubt, but I've not been able to think of a circumstance where replacing it with "apparently" would indicate a greater level of trust.